# MySQL Workbench - View Query Results as Table - EASY

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

A quick one. Fairly new to MySQL and Workbench so apologies for the nub question.

**How do I export a simple query's results to a table which I can easily copy (to Excel)?**

My problem:

When I run a simple query like this:

```
SELECT POSTED_DATE,
       count(*) as TotalNumber
FROM djs.diablo
GROUP BY POSTED_DATE;
```

It returns an unwieldy text format (See below)

> - ---------------- + ---------------- +
>
> | POSTED_DATE      | TotalNumber      |
>
> - ---------------- + ---------------- +
>
> | 20121230         | 283255           |
>
> | 20121231         | 273134           |
>
> | 20130101         | 105996           |
>
> | 20130102         | 268065           |
>
> | 20130103         | 286055           |
>
> | 20130104         | 253300           |
>
> | 20130105         | 228801           |
>
> - ---------------- + ---------------- +
>
> 7 rows

What I'd like is the same as if you select the top 1000 rows. It shows the columns in a table, you can copy paste or export from there.

Is this just a setting?

Cheers,
Lucas

Comment: What version are you using?  There should be an export button right above the results table

Comment: 6.0 CE I believe. (Running a long query at the moment and it's frozen)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to change query output layout. You can change it either By:

- Going to the main menu (Query -> Execute (All or Selection) )

  You will notice (Execute (All or Selection) to Text) which is your current view mode for the result.
- Press (Shift + Command + Enter) <--- if you are using a Mac version of workbench

If you changed the layout to table view, you can export result into many formats by clicking on the icon just above the result (a table with a red arrow on it) , labeled as (File:)

- Be aware if your resultset has more than 1000 records. In workbench by default limit is set to 1000 records.
  You can change this Limit from "Preferences"

Comment: Ahhh Thanks Sed. I see what I've done now. I edited the main_menu.xml file so I could rebind execute query to F5. What I did was actually bound execute to text rather than execute (normal).  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the advice, i did know how to see my query result on Mac OS before .... I was clicking on the lightning icon, wich does not print results.